# Código em C pulando entrada do usuário

Tags: c, algoritmo, lógica

Olá!
Sou newbie e estou tentando fazer um programa para ler uma listagem de informações inseridas nele.
Até a primeira linha ele funciona, mas a partir do segundo cadastro ele já não lê mais o nome, colocando o segundo texto "`SEXO: [M/F]`" na linha do nome e o resultado final não sai como esperado.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    // <.Listagem de Cadastrados.>

    char nome1[40], nome2[40], nome3[40];
    char sexo1,sexo2, sexo3;
    float nota1,nota2,nota3;

    printf("Cadastrando 1° pessoa\n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(nome1,40,stdin);
    printf("SEXO [M/F]: ");
    sexo1 = getchar();
    printf("NOTA: ");
    scanf("%f", &nota1);
    printf("--------------------------\n");

    printf("Cadastrando 2° pessoa\n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(nome2,40,stdin);
    printf("SEXO [M/F]: ");
    sexo2 = getchar();
    printf("NOTA: ");
    scanf("%f", &nota2);
    printf("--------------------------\n");

    printf("Cadastrando 3° pessoa\n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(nome3,40,stdin);
    printf("SEXO [M/F]: ");
    sexo3 = getchar();
    printf("NOTA: ");
    scanf("%f", &nota3);

    system("clear"); // limpar tela - mesma ideia do cls no windows.

    printf("Listagem Completa\n\n");
    printf("------------------------------\n");
    printf("NOME SEXO NOTA");
    printf("%s %c %.2f\n",nome1,sexo1,nota1);
    printf("%s %c %.2f\n",nome2,sexo2,nota2);
    printf("%s %c %.2f\n",nome3,sexo3,nota3);
    printf("------------------------------\n");
}
```

*Poderiam me ajudar a entender este problema?
Poderiam sugerir melhorias no código?*

Att.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é com o scanf(), ele lê um float e deixa uma linha vazia no buffer, então quando você usa o fgets() ele lê essa linha vazia.

Só que para limpar o buffer você usou o fflush(stdin), que não é recomendado e até evitado, então não o use.

Uma solução que encontrei foi adicionar um getchar() depois de cada scanf() para ler essa linha vazia e o código não ignora mais as entradas.

Então o código ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    // <.Listagem de Cadastrados.>

    char nome1[40], nome2[40], nome3[40];
    char sexo1,sexo2, sexo3;
    float nota1,nota2,nota3;


    printf("Cadastrando 1° pessoa\n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(nome1,40,stdin);
    printf("SEXO [M/F]: ");
    sexo1 = getchar();
    printf("NOTA: ");
    scanf("%f", &nota1);
    getchar();

    printf("--------------------------\n");

    printf("Cadastrando 2° pessoa\n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(nome2,40,stdin);
    printf("SEXO [M/F]: ");
    sexo2 = getchar();
    printf("NOTA: ");
    scanf("%f", &nota2);
    getchar();

    printf("--------------------------\n");

    printf("Cadastrando 3° pessoa\n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(nome3,40,stdin);
    printf("SEXO [M/F]: ");
    sexo3 = getchar();
    printf("NOTA: ");
    scanf("%f", &nota3);
    getchar();

    system("clear"); // limpar tela - mesma ideia do cls no windows.

    printf("Listagem Completa\n\n");
    printf("------------------------------\n");
    printf("NOME SEXO NOTA\n");
    printf("%s %c %.2f\n",nome1,sexo1,nota1);
    printf("%s %c %.2f\n",nome2,sexo2,nota2);
    printf("%s %c %.2f\n",nome3,sexo3,nota3);
    printf("------------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Deu tudo certo, mas no final(o printf do resultado) n fica tudo na mesma linha; o nome fica em uma e as outras informações ficam na outra. Sabe como resolver?

Comment: A função fgets mantém o '\n' que indica o final da entrada como fazendo parte da string lida (se o tamanho da string lida for menor que o máximo indicado na chamada da função). Uma possibilidade é verificar se o último caractere da string lida é efetivamente o '\n' e se for substituir por '\0'. Pesquise aqui nas respostas que você encontrará sugestões de como resolver.

Comment: Consegui resolver, agradeço bastante pelo apoio!